# I get Error: no such column: a.mapid when the table is defined

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute a SQL query for a game server. I want to have a query that selects, in descending order, the maps the player hasn't finished yet.

This works:

```
select a.mapid, b.mapname 
from (select mapid 
    from inf_maps a 
    where mapid 
    not in (select mapid 
        from inf_times 
        where uid = %d 
        group by uid, mapid)) a 
inner join inf_maps b 
on a.mapid = b.mapid;
```

After adding rewardpoints, it no longer works:

```
select a.mapid, b.mapname, a.rewardpoints 
from (select r.mapid, rewardpoints 
    from inf_maps r, inf_simpleranks_maps srm 
    where r.mapid 
    not in (select mapid 
        from inf_times 
        where uid = %d 
        group by uid, mapid) 
    and r.mapid = srm.mapid 
    order by rewardpoints desc) a, inf_maps b
where a.mapid = b.mapid;
```

Table structure that you should be interested in:

```
inf_maps: mapid, mapname
inf_times: mapid, uid
inf_simpleranks_maps: mapid, rewardpoints
```

I get this error even though it makes no sense, because the table is clearly defined. I also get no errors on error checkers online.

Comment: Check your query make sure you're not missing the comma between `r.mapid` and `rewardpoints`.

Comment: Why did you change from ANSI JOIN to old style cross products when you added this?

Comment: The query looks fine. (In spite of a join syntax you should have stopped using more than twenty years ago and a superfluous order by clause). You have renamed the alias from `a` to `r`.  I suppose your real query still contains an `a.mapid` where it must be `r.mapid` now.

Comment: I'm not missing the comma. I changed from the JOIN to this bad cross product because I thought the problem came from there, but it doesn't. 
My real query is exactly the one I posted :(

Comment: Strange. I don't see any error and am not getting any: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10ee620bc589e4ad76574737c620c356

Comment: I'm not getting any error either. This is a sourcemod plugin. I am 100% positive I compiled it and loaded it properly, because if I change anything in the text (for example add a random letter somewhere), I get an error for that random letter. It's super strange and I wouldn't be here if it wasn't

Comment: What seems strange is that you would get this exact error message had you either `where a.mapid in` or `and a.mapid = srm.mapid` or with, say, `order by rewardpoints desc) x`. It seems impossible you get this error with the query you are showing. The most likely is here: `order by rewardpoints desc) a`. Please check for some control character after the `a`. Maybe just copy and paste the query from one editor to another to get rid of possible invisible characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Don't be stupid like me! I had a finite number of characters for the string containing the query set to 256. I modified it to 456 and it works now. Stupid, stupid, stupid.

`char szQuery[456];`

Comment: It's often things like this that cost us time and nerves :-) I'm glad you found it.